# Excel OData feed from Microsoft Graph - authentication issues

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Excel to connect to a Microsoft-Graph OData feed.  Specifically, I'm trying to use the following:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices

I can login in through the Graph Explorer and run this query.  When I try to connect in Excel, I specify the Organizational Account option and login successfully, but I get an error "Access to the resource is forbidden" when I try to retrieve the data.

Is there something else I need to do in Excel to make this work?

Comment: The OA might need the correct permissions on it setup through active directory

Comment: Thanks, Adosi.  I'm pretty new to the permissions required for Microsoft-Graph and Intune.  Can you provide any additional detail or point me to an article online?

Answer (score 1):

The Odata feed functionality to be used within Excel has been disabled by the Microsoft graph team hence you would not be able to do that . Initially it was open and you could do this from within excel by setting up Odata feed to fetch data using Microsoft graph endpoints but some major security issues were found due to which this option was disabled hence you will not be able to do it anymore.